# Man'o'War Battles

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassin's Creed IV, I find Man-o-War's kind of useful as they have a lot of Loot on them. But the problem is I can't defeat them, because they are too strong and have a LOT of health. I even found a Man-o-War docked next to this island with Templars on it, but when you enter it's restricted zone someone starts shooting at you so it's impossible to get on the ship.

IS THERE ANY WAY HOW TO BOARD / DEFEAT A MAN'O'WAR ??

( My Jackdaw has three bars of health and I'm low on metal and iron, which I can't anywhere at all)

Comment: "Three bars of health" doesn't mean anything; the Jackdaw always has 3 bars, even with all upgrades installed. Does your Jackdaw have any upgrades at all?

Answer (score 2):

there are places in the world where a Man'o'War is idle, these i normally find to be areas where you can be detected while you sail, there may be areas outside these however it's easier here because you can see what their light of sight is.

here's is the process i go about capturing them

1. Sail the Jackdaw around into their blind spot behind and aim the ship so it's directly in line
2. when i am as close as i can be i let go of the wheel and run to the front of the Jackdaw and jump off them
3. while swiming to avoid getting shot i remain underwater trying only to come up for air as little as i can, (this part is hit and miss but i find chances of success better with a 3rd health upgrade)
4. Once at the Ma'o'War i climb onto it, being on it stops the sniper attacks (i assume they are snipers)
5. i climb to the top without getting detected and kill of the gunmen on the main masts, using the guns they drop and my own i try and kill off as much of the crew as i can taking out the strongest first.
6. After everyone is dead, jump off the back of the Man'o'War and swim back to the Jackdaw
7. Sail alongside the Man'o'War and fire off a round, the Man'o'War will be instently cripled
8. during the boarding phase you will not fight anyone (at least i don't), instead the only things to do to capture the ships is to blow up barrels and take down the flag

it can take anywhere between 10 - 30 minutes depending on how careful you want to be, obviously a quicker method is a max out Jackdaw but this way is much more fun.

Comment: Yeah, even I figured out to swim under the water and tried to board it but the problem is as soon as I surface that sniper guy shoots me without fail and I die in three shots even though I have the 3rd Health Upgrade. And I tried this like 15 times but I keep dieing every single time !!

Comment: @Tushara hmmm, i only have up to the 3rd health upgrade, it is kinda hit and miss that first part since alot of the time when i get there just one more shot would have killed me, but once your on the ship it's a lot more easier and fun, the key i found was trying to reduce the distance you'd need to swim which is why i used the Jackdaw and that bit which sticks out the front, the snipers don't start shooting until your in the water

Comment: @Tushara while i don't have it the i think the Mayan Armour may reduce the damage they do, i'm not sure if it's that one of the Templar Armour but one reduces bullet damage, but as i said i didn't have it

Comment: @Tushara another trick is if you are running out of air, let it drop to the lowest level and come back up while still swimming, after being hit once go back under, the air you recovered will give you a bit more distance underwater (don't wait until your air has fully recovered)

Comment: Good idea but the problem are the Forts, they are hard to beat and I need Iron and Metal for better Hull Armor, better Mortar and Broadside Cannons. That's why I wanted to defeat Man of Wars as they have lots of Loot...

Comment: As soon as I surface that sniper guy shoots me without fail so like I told you I die in three shots ...

Answer (score 0):

Man'o'wars are generally for later in the game once your Jackdaw is built up enough. *They should be avoided* until you are maxed out or very closed to maxed out.

A strategy you can use if you absolutely have to take down a Man'o'war is destroy the little Brigs around them (Man'o'wars are rarely alone) and board them to heal your Jackdaw mid combat.

When boarding a Man'o'war be ready for additional harder objectives to achieve victory, (kill the captain, tear off the flag, kill many more enemies, etc)

Comment: Yeah but is it possible to board a Man of War alone by swimming up to it and climbing it ?? Because as I mention above, I found a Man of War docked next to a cove. And if I try to swim up to it some guy whose invisible shoots me. And if I try to swim through it underwater, as soon as I surface that same guy shoots me, so I die even before I reach the Ship.

Comment: that docked man'o'war is part of the world environment, and it plays a part later in the game.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to board a Man'o'War by swimming up to it, but getting on boats like that is VERY difficult. I tried climbing onto a smaller ship, and it took me a good while to get in its way to get aboard.

Personally, I would suggest going after small ships, then getting the hunters on your tail. They generally carry ok loot drops for early-mid game, and even with the default Jackdaw you can avoid going under 2 bars of health (so that you repair up to full by selecting "Repair the Jackdaw"). After hunters get too small, frigates are good loot.

If you really must go after a Man'o'War, treat it like you are attacking a fort. Use your speed; launch mortars from afar and often; and stay broadside, while aiming at the hull.

Comment: I am currently having two "crossing swords", which is two wanted levels but I've only seen one hunter till now. What I really want is mostly Iron and Metal, which is really scarce. Do I need to be near cities for Hunters to find me ??

Comment: You don't need to be near cities, but it helps to not fast travel as that will often wipe out smaller wanted levels. Keep taking down smaller ships - ones that you can reliably eliminate with little to no damage. Then just sail around. It might take 5 minutes to find a hunter, but they always carry some metal (iron isn't found in this game at all).